# Replace fullwidth punctuation characters with normal width equivalents

Tags: python, bash, unicode

`file1` contains some `：`s (that's fullwidth) I'd like to turn into regular `:`s (that's our regular colon). How do I do this in bash? Perhaps a python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With all due respect, *python* isn’t the right tool for this job; *perl* is:

```
perl -CSAD -i.orig -pe 'tr[：][:]' file1
```

or

```
perl -CSAD -i.orig -pe 'tr[\x{FF1A}][:]' file1
```

or

```
perl -CSAD -i.orig -Mcharnames=:full -pe 'tr[\N{FULLWIDTH COLON}][:]' file1
```

or

```
perl -CSAD -i.orig -Mcharnames=:full -pe 'tr[\N{FULLWIDTH EXCLAMATION MARK}\N{FULLWIDTH QUOTATION MARK}\{FULLWIDTH NUMBER SIGN}\N{FULLWIDTH DOLLAR SIGN}\N{FULLWIDTH PERCENT SIGN}\N{FULLWIDTH AMPERSAND}\{FULLWIDTH APOSTROPHE}\N{FULLWIDTH LEFT PARENTHESIS}\N{FULLWIDTH RIGHT PARENTHESIS}\N{FULLWIDTH ASTERISK}\N{FULLWIDTH PLUS SIGN}\N{FULLWIDTH COMMA}\N{FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS}\N{FULLWIDTH FULL STOP}\N{FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS}][\N{EXCLAMATION MARK}\N{QUOTATION MARK}\N{NUMBER SIGN}\N{DOLLAR SIGN}\N{PERCENT SIGN}\{AMPERSAND}\N{APOSTROPHE}\N{LEFT PARENTHESIS}\N{RIGHT PARENTHESIS}\N{ASTERISK}\N{PLUS SIGN}\N{COMMA}\{HYPHEN-MINUS}\N{FULL STOP}\N{SOLIDUS}]' file1
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree that Python is not the most effective tool for this purpose. While the options presented so far are good, `sed` is another good tool to have around:

```
sed -i 's/\xEF\xBC\x9A/:/g' file.txt
```

The -i option causes sed to edit the file in place, as in tchrist's perl example. Note that `\xEF\xBC\x9A` is the UTF-8 equivalent of the UTF-16 value `\xFF1A`. [This page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1a/index.htm) is a useful reference in case you need to deal with different encodings of the same Unicode value.

Comment: Dealing with things at an encoding level is always the wrong way to go. You should never have to spell out particular bit patterns from this or that encoding.  You should always deal with logical characters only. Anything else is madness.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into Python's [`unicodedata.normalize()`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).

It allows you to take a unicode string, and normalize it to a specific form, for example:

`unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', thestring)`

Here's a table of the different normalization forms from [Unicode Standard Annex #15](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms):

[image]

---

If you only want to replace specific characters, you could use `unicode.translate()`.

```
>>> orig = u'\uFF1A:'
>>> table = {0xFF1A: u':'}
>>> print repr(orig)
>>> print repr(orig.translate(table))
u'\uFF1A:'
u'::'
```

Comment: What’s the `python -c ....` equivalent to the Perl one-liners I just gave?

Comment: Added an attempt at a one-liner :)

Comment: -1 You obviously haven't tested this. (1) `u'\x{FF1A}'` is invalid syntax -- use `u'\uFF1A'` (2) `string.maketrans` is for `str` objects, not `unicode` objects -- you need `table = {0xFF1A: u':'}` (3) you haven't decoded the input `str` object from utf8/big5/gbk/shift_jis/whatever to `unicode`

Comment: Oops, yes, I had only tested with non unicode.. thanks for pointing it out and explaining all the corrections! Looks like I was getting a bit ahead of myself..

Comment: @Acorn: Translating a full-width colon to the digit 9 is a somewhat strange example.

Comment: @John: Right, it's easier to see that it's working though. The difference between a 9 and a colon is nice and clear.

Comment: @Acorn: Clear?? How can you tell by looking what kind of colon you have printed? Use `repr()` ... the difference between `u'\uff1a'` and `u'\x3a'` is *very* clear.

Comment: @John: I'm not sure I understand.. `repr(u'\uFF1A:'.translate({0xFF1A: u':'}))` gives `"u'::'"`

Comment: @Acorn: If you mess up the translation table, `repr(result)` would contain the original u'\uff1a` -- `print result` would display a full-width colon which can be visually very similar to the ASCII colon.

Comment: @John: Oh right, a `:` vs `\uff1a` .. your earlier comment made me think I was going to somehow get `\x3a` as output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `tr`:

```
cat file.ext | tr "：" ":" > file_new.ext
```

Comment: @Mike: That’s because *tr* doesn’t work with Unicode.  Perl does, though.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x you can use the `unicode.translate` method to translate a single Unicode codepoint to 0, 1 or more codepoints, using

```
replacement_string = original_string.translate(table)
```

The following code sets up a translation table that will map the full-width equivalents of all ASCII graphic characters to their ASCII equivalents:

```
# ! is 0x21 (ASCII) 0xFF01 (full); ~ is 0x7E (ASCII) 0xFF5E (full)
table = dict((x + 0xFF00 - 0x20, unichr(x)) for x in xrange(0x21, 0x7F))
```

(reference: see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms))

If you want to treat spaces similarly, do `table[0x3000] = u' '`