# Convert exotic charset to string with python

Tags: python, string, character-encoding

After parsing some webpage with utf-8 coding, I realize that I obtain characters that I can't manipulaten, though it is readable by the means of print.

```
>> print data
Ａ　Ｄｅｕｃｅ

>> data
u'\uff21\u3000\uff24\uff45\uff55\uff43\uff45'
```

How can I get this into a decent coding using Python?
I would like to obtain

```
>> my_variable
'A Deuce'
```

(I mean being able to cast that text in a variable as a "regular" string)
I saw several solutions related to that topic but did not find relevant answer (mainly based on encoding/decoding in other charset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5863893/1126841):

```
>>> table = dict([(x + 0xFF00 - 0x20, unichr(x)) for x in xrange(0x21, 0x7F)] + [(0x3000, unichr(0x20))])
>>> data.translate(table)
u'A Deuce'
```

The `translate` method takes a dictionary that maps one Unicode code point to another. In this case, it maps the full-width Latin alphabet (which is essentially part of the ASCII character set shifted up to the range 0xFF01-0xFF5E) to the "normal" ASCII character set. For example, 0xFF21 (full-width A) maps to 0x41 (ASCII A), 0xFF22 (full-width B) maps to 0x42 (ASCII B), etc.

Comment: Thanks you, it is working fine. Could I ask you for a bit of explanation? I am confused about that first line

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is built into the [unicodedata](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) module:

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', 'Ａ　Ｄｅｕｃｅ')
'A Deuce'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Python 3, which has better printing support for Unicode characters.  Here's a sample:

```
>>> s=u'\uff21\u3000\uff24\uff45\uff55\uff43\uff45'
>>> print(s)
Ａ　Ｄｅｕｃｅ
>>> s
'Ａ\u3000Ｄｅｕｃｅ'
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name('\u3000')
'IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE'
>>> print(ascii(s))
'\uff21\u3000\uff24\uff45\uff55\uff43\uff45'
```